# How to repaint a MDIChild form when the MDIChild itself contains containers such as TPanel with aligned := alClient and ParentBackground := False

Tags: delphi, repaint, mdichild

**Summarization:**

Please see Andreas' knowledgeable comments!

==========================================

As shown in the following code, TForm7 is the MDIForm form, TForm8 is the MDIChild form. TForm8 contains an alClient aligned panel, which further contains a TPaintBox. If the TForm8's panel's ParentBackground is set to False, I cannot trigger TForm8's paintbox's paint event from TForm7. I am wondering why would this happen, and how can I trigger TForm8's paintbox's paint event without exlicitly refering to it. Any suggestion is appreciated!

<strike>Note: If I call `Self.Repaint` withint TForm8, for example inside its Click event, TForm8's paintbox's paint event can be triggered. It cannot be triggered only when I call `form8.repaint` outside TForm8. I am wondering why would this happen?</strike>

Possibly relevant SO pages:
[How to repaint a parent form while a modal form is active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288813/how-to-repaint-a-parent-form-while-a-modal-form-is-active)

Unit that contains the MDIForm form.

```
    unit Unit7;

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs;

    type
      TForm7 = class(TForm)
        procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FormClick(Sender: TObject);

      end;

    var
      Form7: TForm7;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    uses
      Unit8;

    procedure TForm7.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      TForm8.Create(Self);
    end;

    procedure TForm7.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      TForm8(ActiveMDIChild).Repaint;
    end;

    end.
```

Dfm of the above Unit.

```
    object Form7: TForm7
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Form7'
      ClientHeight = 379
      ClientWidth = 750
      Color = clBtnFace
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWindowText
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Font.Style = []
      FormStyle = fsMDIForm
      OldCreateOrder = False
      OnClick = FormClick
      OnShow = FormShow
      PixelsPerInch = 96
      TextHeight = 13
    end
```

Unit that contains the MDIChild form.

```
    unit Unit8;

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

    type
      TForm8 = class(TForm)
        pb1: TPaintBox;
        pnl1: TPanel;
        procedure pb1Paint(Sender: TObject);
        procedure pb1Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
        fCounter: Integer;

      end;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm8.pb1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Self.Repaint;
    end;

    procedure TForm8.pb1Paint(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Self.pb1.Canvas.TextOut(30, 30, IntToStr(Self.fCounter));
      Self.fCounter := Self.fCounter + 1;
    end;

    end.
```

Dfm of the above Unit.

```
    object Form8: TForm8
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Form8'
      ClientHeight = 226
      ClientWidth = 233
      Color = clBtnFace
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWindowText
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Font.Style = []
      FormStyle = fsMDIChild
      OldCreateOrder = False
      Visible = True
      PixelsPerInch = 96
      TextHeight = 13
      object pnl1: TPanel
        Left = 0
        Top = 0
        Width = 233
        Height = 226
        Align = alClient
        ShowCaption = False
        TabOrder = 0
        object pb1: TPaintBox
          Left = 1
          Top = 1
          Width = 231
          Height = 224
          Align = alClient
          OnClick = pb1Click
          OnPaint = pb1Paint
          ExplicitLeft = 56
          ExplicitTop = -64
          ExplicitWidth = 105
          ExplicitHeight = 105
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: An aside. Why do you call `Repaint`? Normally you call Invalidate which calls InvalidateRect which in turn posts a WM_PAINT message. This message only gets processed when your message queue gets pumped once the app becomes idle. It's a more efficient way to do things because it minimises the number of times you actually have to paint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the case:

Believe it or not, the "normal" behaviour is that, if you repaint a form (or some other container), only that container gets repainted, not the children contained in it. However, with the advent of visual themes, controls got semi-transparent parts, and all of a sudden you need to repaint the child controls when the parent is redrawn, simply because the children need to reblend into the new background.

My hypothesis is (relatively) readily validated by scrutinizing the VCL source code, e.g.

```
procedure TWinControl.CMInvalidate(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  { Removed irrelevant code to avoid copyvio issues. }  
      InvalidateRect(WindowHandle, nil, not (csOpaque in ControlStyle));
      { Invalidate child windows which use the parentbackground when themed }
      if ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled then
        for I := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
          if csParentBackground in Controls[I].ControlStyle then
            Controls[I].Invalidate;
  { Removed irrelevant code to avoid copyvio issues. }
end;
```

Therefore, when `ParentBackground` is set to `false`, and the panel bahaves like a classic panel, it isn't repainted when its parent is. On the other hand, if `ParentBackground` is `true`, it does get repainted along with its parent.

Hence there is no problem, really; you simply expect a behaviour that isn't to be expected.

So you need to repaint the paint box manually, by following David's advice.

Comment: @Andreas: Thank you very much for your knowledgeable comments!

Comment: @Andreas: Could you comment which is recommended, ParentBackground := True or False? I kept ParentBackground false, simply because I thought by setting ParentBackground to false, I can prevent the Parent to paint the Parent's background, to avoid overhead and/or flickering. Could you help to comment whether it is true?

Comment: @Xichen: It probably isn't much of an overhead, but I am pretty sure that `ParentBackground := False` outperforms the other option. But if you work with themes, for instance, if you put a `TPanel` in a `TPageControl`, then you really do need the parent background!

Comment: @Andreas: I forgot to mention in my question (added now): If I call `Self.repaint` within TForm8, the TPaintBox.Repaint `can` be triggered. It cannot triggered when I call `form8.repaint` outside TForm8, for example in TForm7.

Comment: @Xichen: I can't reproduce that behaviour. It **really** shouldn't matter if you do `Form8.Repaint` or `Self.Repaint` if `Self = Form8`!

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for your time and sorry for this trouble! Please have a rest and take a cup of coffee, and I will post the sample code.

Comment: @Xichen I can't understand why you want to make life hard for yourself. What problem are you solving by setting ParentBackground to false?

Comment: @Andreas: It is my fault. As you expect, what I added cannot be reproduced. Sorry for causing your trouble!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call `pb1.Invalidate` when you want the paint box to re-draw itself.

Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @David: I think you didn't read his entire question. He wants to repaint the paint box by calling `Repaint` (or `Invalidate`) of the 
*parent form*, that is, the MDI child containing the panel with the paint box. This works unless the panel has `ParentBackground` set to `true`. Why the OP wishes to do this, I don't know, but I think that's the question, at least. [And, of course, I didn't downvote.]

Comment: @Andreas Well Xichen may want to invalidate the paint box that way, but if it doesn't work, which it doesn't, then doing it the way I suggest will work. I think!

Comment: +1.  Do you know if a moderator can trace who is down-voting?

Comment: @Andreas Given that I'm sitting here on -1 with what seems like the only plausible answer, I'm curious as to whether anyone else will be brave enough to have a go!!

Comment: @jacguate It doesn't really matter. They are entitled to down-vote.

Comment: @jachguate: That has happened, IIRC.

Comment: [Correction: In my original comment I meant `false`, not `true`.]

Comment: @David: Thank you very much for your time! As Andreas mention, I was wondering whether I can just call TForm8's repaint, and let TForm8 call its components' repaint. I mean, if I have various components in TForm8, I wantted to avoid referring to each specific component. :D

Comment: @Xichen Why don't you just set ParentBackground to True, its default value. And please don't call Repaint. Call Invalidate.

Comment: @David: I `feel` by set ParentBackground to False, I can avoid Parent's painting Parent's background. And thank you for your suggestion of `And please don't call Repaint. Call Invalidate.`! I assume it is best practice to `repaint`?

Comment: @David, I know they are entitled to down-vote... maybe I'm too concerned about the only reason to down-vote is the author of the answer, which I think happens here sometimes.

Comment: @Xichen No, you should not be calling Repaint. You should be calling Invalidate. You are better off setting ParentBackground to be True. It's the default for a good reason.

Comment: @jachguate Well, I couldn't possibly imagine why anyone would down-vote just because it was me!!!  ;-)

Comment: @David who knows?, I think that way because I see too many downvotes to your answers recently... anyway, I'm glad you're good with it... another thing to learn from you, hehe. :D

Comment: @jachguate since I hit the rep cap most days, I usually get the last laugh!

Comment: @jachguate since I answer a lot of questions, I can expect a lot of downvotes.

Comment: got it... I really want to reach that cap that frequently... :D